# Eliminating port number in the url

Tags: java, struts, tomcat6

I have a application developing in Java, Strut2 and Tomcat
and is been deployed n Tomcat 6.0
the URL to access is
http://websiste:8181/webAppName/some.action

Now I am trying to change the above url to 
http://website/webAppName/some.action

can you please let me know how to eliminate Port number in URL

Comment: google "fronting tomcat with apache".

Answer (score 3):

You should run the server on port 80 which is default for http.

Comment: Since my other websites which is running on my server uses that port 80 by Apache web server.
I have installed Tomcat upon that so I have pointed to 8181 port. 

WIthout changing the port is not possible?

Comment: The only choice you have is to configure Apache to take requests and redirect them to Tomcat via ajp or URL rewriting. You can't connect directly to tomcat without specifying the port in URL, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You need Tomcat to use port 80 instead of 8181. Port 80 is the default port used when no port is specified. See [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/) for details on how to change the port number.

Edit:
Since you have Apache running on port 80, you can't serve your app from Tomcat on port 80 too. One option is to use Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) (can be dangerous), or the Tomcat's [Apache connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) to get Apache to serve `/webAppName/*` from Tomcat instead of from your other website's resources.

Comment: Since my other websites which is running on my server uses that port 80 by Apache web server.
I have installed Tomcat upon that so I have pointed to 8181 port. 

WIthout changing the port is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the tomcat configuration, it's a simple matter to change it to port 80. More info is available here: http://www.klawitter.de/tomcat80.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to eliminate it :
1) Preferred way : set the server to listen at port 80 instead of 8181 as others have already mentioned
2) Non preferred way : Change Proxy settings in your browser to hit 8181 port instead of 80 for http protocol. This will force you to explicitly use 80 port when trying to reach other web sites.